# Cómo crear método constructor que reciba como parámetro una clase genérica?

Tags: java, poo, clase, constructor

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase en el cual tengo que hacer una clase que funcione como un array diáamico, osea, que lo que tengo que hacer es lo que vendría siendo el arraylist de hacendado.

en principio mas o menos los métodos los voy sacando, el add, indexOf...

el problema es que no se como hacer el constructor para poder crear objetos de mi clase generica partiendo de un objeto de esta misma clase.

```
DynArray da = new DynArray(new Integer[] {1,2,3});
DynArray dad=new DynArray(da);//esto falla;

public class DynArray<T> {´
      private Object[] dato;
      public DynArray(DynArray < ? extends T > pObj) {
          this.dato = pObj;//aqui es donde me da el fallo! "incompatible types: dynarray cannot convert to object "
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que ambas variables son de diferentes tipos y por esa razón el compilador da el error.

La **solución** es copiar los elementos de la anterior lista en la nueva.

```java
class DynArray<T> 
{
    private Object[] dato;
    private int length;

    public DynArray()
    {
        //Tamaño inicial del arreglo
        dato = new Object[10];
    }

    public DynArray(DynArray <? extends T > pObj) 
    {
        //Obtenemos la longitud de la anterior lista 
        length = pObj.length;
        dato = new Object[length]; //Creamos el nuevo arreglo 
        for(int i = 0; i != length; ++i) //Copiamos los elementos de la anterior lista en la nueva
            dato[i] = pObj.get(i);
    }

    public T get(int index)
    {
        return (T)dato[index];
    }

    public void add(T element)
    {
        dato[length++] = element;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return length;
    }
}
```

He creado un constructor por defecto, un método `get`, `add` y `size` para poder hacer la prueba del código.

**Test:**

```java
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        var list1 = new DynArray<Integer>();
        list1.add(10);
        list1.add(11);

        var list2 = new DynArray<Integer>(list1);
        for(int i = 0; i != list2.size(); ++i)
        {
            System.out.println(list2.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```